# Sending audio message with Twilio

Tags: audio, twilio, mms, twilio-php

I need to send audio message for a client. I'm using the API like in [this link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages):

```
<?php
require_once('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

$sid = "ACf2a000728962e9b8135bf456d89cfd7a"; 
$token = "{{ auth_token }}"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

$client->account->messages->sendMessage("+14158141829", "+15558675309", "Jenny please?! I love you <3", "http://www.example.com/love_words.wav");
```

The message does not get delivered and I don't get any error message. It works if I'm using text and/or image but not with audio.

**How can I send an audio message with Twilio?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the correct MIME type header in the server where file is allocated
Please take a look at this URL
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/accepted-mime-types

If Content is invalid you will see in Twilio portal SMS/MMS logs the following:

```
Error: 12300 - Invalid Content-Type
```

For example:

```
curl -v -O http://www.schiffert.me/select1.wav
```

Returns:

```
Content-Type: audio/x-wav
```

which is invalid

But

```
curl -v -O http://www.schiffert.me/feedback.mp3
```

Returns:

```
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
```

Comment: Ok I'll try that tomorrow but I'm pessimistic that will work. Instead of "http://www.example.com/love_words.wav" I'll have audio.php and inside I'll process the file with the proper headers.

Comment: Just edited answer, please take a look at the response where lover_words.wav reside

Comment: Yes that was the problem, but man is a nightmare to actually find a proper audio media MIME type for sending the audio message.